# Threads program, type in an input and stop the "hello world" input and type in another input all the way till you type in "quit"?

Tags: java

this is a program that will print out "Hello world!" every third second. You will get an input box to write in a message, but how can I stop the message "Hello world!" when I type in a new input? and for each time I write a new message the message before will also stop writing?
For example:
console output:
Hello World!
Hello World!
Hello World!
Win! (then I type in Win! and stop the Hello world!)
Win! (Win continues every three second until I type in another input text).
Smile! (New input: Smile and "Win!" stopped.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        
        Thread t1 = new Thread(new myThread());
        Thread t2 = new Thread(new inputThread());
        
        t1.start();
        t2.start();

        t1.join();
        t2.join();
    }
}
```

```
public class myThread implements Runnable {
    
    private boolean stop = false;

    public synchronized void stop() {
        this.stop = true;
    }

    private synchronized boolean continues() {
        return this.stop == false;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(continues()) {
            System.out.println("Hello world!");

            try {
                Thread.sleep(3000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
               
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
public class inputThread implements Runnable {
    
    private boolean stop = false;

    public synchronized void stop() {
        this.stop = true;
    }

    private synchronized boolean continues() {
        return this.stop == false;
    }
      
    @Override
    public void run() {
        
        while(continues()) {
            String message = showInputDialog("Write your message, type quit to shut down!");
            
            if(message.equals("quit")) {
                break;
            }

            else {
                System.out.println(message);
                 try {
                     Thread.sleep(3000);
                 } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    
                 }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How about just having a global `message` String that is initially set to `"Hello World!"` and determines what is printed by `myThread`.  Then your input thread would set `message` to the new value and that would then be what is printed every 3 seconds.

It does seem like you're all set to stop the original `myThread` if you want to.  You could pass the reference to it in `t1` to the constructor of `inputThread` and then you could call `stop` on that reference when you want to stop the thread.

Answer (score 0):

The [Thread API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html) used to have, among others, a `stop()` method to, well, stop threads. Such methods were unsafe and have been deprecated. [This](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/concurrency/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html) explains why and what you should use instead.

Comment: so how does this look with my coding example? @JustAnotherDeveloper